# angularjs : logging scope property in directive link function displays undefined

Tags: angularjs, javascript-framework

I have this basic [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XXtz7pHaPJ7IgQfTM5nl?p=preview) which just implements a basic "Hello, X" directive.
In the link function I am logging `scope.name` but I get `undefined`? Why is it so? Shouldn't it log the value of `name` property in console?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a known "problem" where interpolation of `@` attributes happens after linking function is invoked. There is a [pull request open](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1555) to change this issue but it is not clear if this one is going to be merged.

In the meantime a way of getting an interpolated value is by observing an attribute like so:

```
attrs.$observe('hello', function(changedValue){
     console.log(scope.name);
});
```

And the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/Lnw6LuadTLhhcOTsPC8w?p=preview

So, at the end of the day this is a bit confusing behavior of AngularJS that might be changed in the future.

Comment: okay...so, since the `{{ }}` expressions aren't evaluated yet, in the linking phase, it returns undefined. Using a constant string instead of an interpolation however returns the correct value.

Comment: In this case is there every a scenario where '@myAttr' is useful?  I've had to revert to using the attrs variable instead, which feels a bit sloppy..

Comment: I don't know how I landed here, but just to add, as of today, the interpolation of `"@"` attributes happens before the linking function is invoked. See [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2650-looking-at-attribute-interpolation-workflow-changes-in-angularjs.htm) post about the same.

Answer (score 2):

Pawel is right (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14552200/287070) but I wanted to add that the problem is that any attribute that contains {{}} interpolation will be set to null in the attrs parameter during the link function as the first $digest since the compilation has not yet run to evaluate these.

The fact that @ bindings are null in linking functions is just a symptom of this.

Currently there is no real fix, since we can't start running $digests in the middle of the compilation process.  So $observe (or $watch) is the only real way to get hold of these values.

Comment: This seems confusing because it also affects attributes that don't use interpolation. I just wanted to pass an argument to a directive through a DOM attribute string, nothing too fancy, but the fact that I have to use $observe to actually get at this value is very unintuitive.

Answer (score 0):

For those in 2015 who are reading this post, please note that the way Angular handles `"@"` attributes has changed.
Angular 1.2 onwards, interpolation occurs prior to the invocation of the linking function.

An excellent post on this topic is [present here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2650-looking-at-attribute-interpolation-workflow-changes-in-angularjs.htm).